Join text file content to existing dataframe
I have a dataframe with metadata df_meta that has the uri of text files with the content that I require:



id
s3_uri




1
s3://bucket1/prefix


2
s3://bucket2/another_prefix


3
s3://bucket3/a_different_prefix



Note that the files can be in different buckets, so I can't do a standard spark.read.text(path).
I opted to instead try the following:
s3_list = (
            df_meta.select("s3_uri")
            .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
            .collect()
        )
df_want = spark.read.text(s3_list, wholetext=True).withColumn("path", input_file_name())

And thereafter join the two dataframes using the path column.
This works for a few million records, but once my list size goes 100m+ then spark reader fails on the "Listing leaf files and directories.." step. (I have increased compute configs - mem, cpu, tasks... to no avail).
I realize I have a small file type of problem, but moving the list of files into a separate folder and then reading is not an option at present.
Any input on how make this more efficient?
